# Doubts about popen

Tags: php

Is there any way to make popen supports operators like &, | etc?

Example:

```
    $cmd = "/bin/sh -c" . " \"" . "whoami && uname" ."\"";
    $han = popen($cmd, 'r');
    echo(fread($han, 2096));
    pclose($han);
```

Just the first command ( whoami ) gets executed rather than both

I know there are other functions, but I'm talking just about popen

Answer (score 0):

Use [`proc_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) with your command to ensure `&&` will work:

> [`proc_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) is similar to [`popen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) but provides a much greater degree of control over the program execution.

---

```php
<?php

    $cmd = "/bin/sh -c" . " \"" . "whoami && uname" ."\"";
    $han = proc_open($cmd, [ 0 => [ "pipe", "w" ]], $pipes);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[0]);
    proc_close($han);
```

---

#### [Online demo](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoMwEETv/YphEVGw1bu1/RArYtOlEZpkMSn9/DSavQw7u/NGtMR4vYuW0wlpCmVeGEDtc7Wt1zgrwgWEBx36024xK8oSX7sYTh6lS5@jerEpKptTsxO21c5qMKLDcEtCsgpTkyCEaWpQ7Luv@1zMSjv4sPFi5jeHWTkb2AZf5bexm@pcc/DVx3mu9sbkxvgH)

---

Output of above:

```
runner
Linux
```

Comment: Thanks! I already know about that, I just would like to do the same thing but for popen

Comment: Not sure why but `popen` does not work with the `&&` while proc_open does work.

Comment: The funny thing is that 2>&1 works...